# SQL Another solution to this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone think of a different solution to this query (or fix an error in mine if you see one? My solution isn't giving me the correct result apparently (thats what my professor says) and he won't tell me why. Any help is appreciated. Question, ERD, input and my output below:

Output:

```
2   Euronext Paris          EP  2019-04-22 13:06:36
1   London Stock Exchange   LSE 2019-03-28 13:06:36
5   Moscow Stock Exchange   MSE NULL
6   NASDAQ Stock Exchange   NASDAQ  2019-05-09 13:06:36
3   New York Stock Exchange NYSE    2019-05-20 13:06:36
4   Tokyo Stock Exchange    TSE 2019-04-10 13:06:36
```

> - For each stock listed at each stock exchange, display the exchange name, 
>     stock symbol and the date and time when that the stock was last traded. Sort the output by stock exchange name, stock symbol.  If a stock has not been traded show NULL for the date last traded.

```
SELECT
stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, 
stock_exchange.name stock_exchange_name,
stock_exchange.symbol,
nvl(to_char(max(trade.transaction_time), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'NULL') as last_traded
FROM stock_exchange 
LEFT JOIN trade
ON trade.stock_ex_id = stock_exchange.stock_ex_id
GROUP BY stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol
ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_exchange.symbol;
```

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw48v.png)

Comment: I actually don't see any error in the logic of your query.  Are you certain that the professor took the time to read your answer?

Comment: Yea. Said "its not returning the correct result set". Won't tell me what is wrong though.

Comment: You're displaying stock exchange symbols,  not stock.  I don't see them anywhere in your SELECT

Comment: "For each *stock* listed at each stock exchange, display the exchange name, stock symbol and the date and time when that the stock was last traded", I agree with @JimCastro, you have only exchanges, not individual stock.

Comment: Not sure if this is what your professor is referring to, but I note that the instructions don't indicate that `ex_id` should be included in the output.

Comment: Don't you need to join Stock_listing table to get all stocks?

Comment: Thanks guys. I got the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your ERD is missing the relationship between Trade and Stock_Listing. Stock_Listing is where you get the Stock Symbol:

```
SELECT
    stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, 
    stock_exchange.name stock_exchange_name,
    stock_listing.symbol,
    nvl(to_char(max(trade.transaction_time), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'NULL') as last_traded
FROM stock_exchange 
    JOIN stock_listing
    ON stock_exchange.stock_ex_id =  stock_listing.stock_ex_id
    LEFT JOIN trade
    ON trade.stock_ex_id = stock_listing.stock_ex_id
    and trade.stock_id =  stock_listing.stock_id
GROUP BY stock_exchange.stock_ex_id, stock_exchange.name, stock_listing.symbol
ORDER BY stock_exchange.name, stock_listing.symbol;
```

Notes:

1. Do you need to include `stock_ex_id` in the result set
2. Do you need to include the string `NULL` when the Stock hasn't been traded. Won't a blank (i.e. `null`) suffice?

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I didn't see that. Such a minor mistake. I thought he meant the stock exchange symbol

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select sl.stock_ex_id, se.name, sl.symbol, max(t.trade_time)
from stock_listing sl join  -- inner join should be fine
     stock_exchange se
     on se.stock_ex_id = sl.stock_ex_id left join
     trade t
     on t.stock_id = sl.stock_id
group by sl.stock_ex_id, se.name, sl.symbol;
```

The question is phrased as "for each stock listing", so in my mind, it makes sense to start with that table and keep all its rows.

The `max()` will return `NULL` the value rather than `'NULL'` the string, but that seems consistent with the question.